# php and chmod does not work

Tags: php, chmod

Hi I want to write a file by using php, but first I should set permissions. When I try `chmod($file,0777);` it doesn't work and returns false.

What should I do for enable chmod function?

Comment: Is PHP creating the file you want to write to, or does it already exists on disk?

Comment: Is a PHP error being thrown?  When chmod fails, it's usually because the file doesn't exist, or the user that PHP is running under doesn't have appropriate permissions.

Comment: Check you haven't got safe mode on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can do one thing.....go to console and see the file writes and its user using ll command...
if user is not a apache user then its will gives you error even if you are syntactically right..so change the group and owner of file to apache using chgrp and chrown command and then run the code...you can see the output........